# How Can I Force Each Image in a Bootstrap Row to be the Same Height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, height

I have three images in the same row and I want all of their heights to be the same (aspect ratio preserved).

I've tried making the parent container holding the images (.carousel-content-container) 'display:flex;' and giving each inner div a 'flex: (aspect ratio of img);', but that didn't seem to work -- perhaps because it interferes with Bootstrap columns? Does anyone know of a way that doesn't feel like a hack?

Any help on this front would be very appreciated! See the image link below to look at the problem.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLPZS.jpg)

HTML (Carousel section):

```
<section class="portfolio-section">


        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="false">

         <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 carousel-content-container">
                  <img src="./imgs/art/the_beach.png" alt="beach img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 carousel-content-container">
                  <img src="./imgs/art/joyce3.jpg" alt="joyce img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 carousel-content-container">
                  <img src="./imgs/art/flower.jpeg" alt="flower img">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            ... OTHER CAROUSEL ITEMS

         ... CAROUSEL PREVIOUS AND NEXT SLIDE BUTTONS

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.portfolio-section .container-fluid {
  background-color: #342b38;
  padding: 7% 5%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* each image takes up 100% of parent div container (.carousel-content-container) */
.portfolio-section .carousel-content-container img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px #1f1921;
}


.portfolio-section .carousel-inner{
  height: 20%;
}

.portfolio-section .row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.portfolio-section .col-lg-5, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set all images to width: 100%;. You have to decide whether the height or width is more important. Or else the pictures will be stretched.

Maybe min-height and/or max-height would help to adjust the size?

For dynamic width of the bootstrap containers use col-md-auto

Comment: whoops, kind of forget about that. Thank you!! I just settled for changing the min-height.